# How do you close/hide a html navigation tab in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am doing a Project and I want to be able to hide/close a tab as the tab will stay open until you refresh the page.

**Closed:**
[image]
**Open:**
[image]

I am using javascript to get it to open and display the tabcontent. However I would like to make it close when you click off the tabs and when you click on the tab title.

**JS:**

```
function openPage(pageName, elmnt, color) {
  // Hide all elements with class="tabcontent" by default */
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Remove the background color of all tablinks/buttons
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink1");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
  }

  // Show the specific tab content
  document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";

  // Add the specific color to the button used to open the tab content
  elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

I'm sorry if someone has already asked this question but I would like some help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the code for closing all tabs into a separate function and then directly call this function when you want to close all tabs:

```
function closeAll()
{
  // Hide all elements with class="tabcontent" by default */
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Remove the background color of all tablinks/buttons
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink1");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
  }
}

function openPage(pageName, elmnt, color) {
  closeAll();

  // Show the specific tab content
  document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";

  // Add the specific color to the button used to open the tab content
  elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

// close all tabs
closeAll();
```

Comment: how would you use these functions to close the tab onclick then?

Comment: In the click handler for your tab you will check whether the given tab has `style.display` equal to `block` - if yes, then it will hide it, otherwise it will show it.

Comment: This code only closes the current tab when you open a new one however i would like all of the tabs to close when you click off the element and when you press on one of the tab titles again e.g. the Qualifications tab

Comment: Can you provide a JSfiddle ?